# Group by multiple columns and sum other multiple columns

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate, plyr, data.table

I have a data frame with about 200 columns, out of them I want to group the table by first 10 or so which are factors and sum the rest of the columns.

I have list of all the column names which I want to group by and the list of all the cols which I want to aggregate.

The output format that I am looking for needs to be the same dataframe with same number of cols, just grouped together.

Is there a solution using packages `data.table`, `plyr` or any other?

Answer (score 23):

The [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) way is :

```
DT[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=list(col1,col2,col3,...)]
```

or

```
DT[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=colnames(DT)[1:10]]
```

where `.SD` is the (S)ubset of (D)ata *excluding* group columns. (Aside: If you need to refer to group columns generically, they are in `.BY`.)

Answer (score 23):

**See below for a more  modern answer using `dplyr::across`**.

The `dplyr` way would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2, col3) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

You can further specify the columns to be summarised or excluded from the `summarise_each` by using the special functions mentioned in the help file of `?dplyr::select`.

Answer (score 20):

In base R this would be...

```
aggregate( as.matrix(df[,11:200]), as.list(df[,1:10]), FUN = sum)
```

**EDIT**:
The aggregate function has come a long way since I wrote this. None of the casting above is necessary.

```
aggregate( df[,11:200], df[,1:10], FUN = sum )
```

And there are a variety of ways to write this. Assuming the first 10 columns are named `a1` through `a10` I like the following, even though it is verbose.

```
aggregate(. ~ a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10, data = dat, FUN = sum)
```

(You could use paste to construct the formula and use `formula`)

Answer (score 19):

This seems like a task for ddply (I use the 'baseball' dataset which is included with plyr):

```
library(plyr)
groupColumns = c("year","team")
dataColumns = c("hr", "rbi","sb")
res = ddply(baseball, groupColumns, function(x) colSums(x[dataColumns]))
head(res)
```

This gives per groupColumns the sum of the columns specified in dataColumns.

Answer (score 10):

Using plyr::ddply:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dtfr, .(name1, name2, namex), numcolwise(sum))
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's consider this example :

```
df <- data.frame(a = 'a', b = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), c = 1:5, d = 11:15,
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

**Update `dplyr` 1.1.0 onwards**

You may use `pick` to select columns -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(pick(where(is.factor))) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum))
```

Or use the `.by` argument.

```
df %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum), .by = where(is.factor))
```

---

**Before `dplyr` 1.1.0**

`_all`, `_at` and `_if` verbs are now superseded and we use `across` now to group all the factor columns and sum all the other columns, we can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum))

#  a     b         c     d
#  <fct> <fct> <int> <int>
#1 a     a         3    23
#2 a     b        12    42
```

To group all factor columns and sum numeric columns :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

---

We can also do this by position but have to be careful of the number since it doesn't count the grouping columns.

```
df %>% group_by(across(1:2)) %>% summarise(across(1:2, sum))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this with dplyr that would be generic (don't need list of columns) would be:

```
df %>% group_by_if(is.factor) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric,sum,na.rm = TRUE)
```