# R aggregate dataframe on two variables and apply function

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe which I'd like to aggregate over two variables applying the function mean on each meassurement. Here the head of the dataframe:

```
  Subject Activity         meassureA         meassureB         meassureC       meassureD
1       1  running         0.2820216      -0.037696218       -0.13489730       -0.3282802
2       1  running         0.2558408      -0.064550029       -0.09518634       -0.2292069
3       1  walking         0.2548672       0.003814723       -0.12365809       -0.2751579
4       2  running         0.3433705      -0.014446221       -0.16737697       -0.2299235
```

Now, I would like to get something like this:

```
  Subject Activity         meassureA         meassureB         meassureC       meassureD
1       1  running         mean(S1,A1)      mean(S1,A1)       mean(S1,A1)       mean(S1,A1)
2       1  walking         mean(S1,A2)      mean(S1,A2)       mean(S1,A2)       mean(S1,A2)
3       2  running         mean(S2,A1)      mean(S2,A1)       mean(S2,A1)       mean(S2,A1)
4       2  walking         mean(S2,A2)      mean(S2,A2)       mean(S2,A2)       mean(S2,A2)
```

Where the value of meassure A is the mean of all values of subject 1 (S1) performing activity running (A1).

I was thinking of using aggregate(), but I am not able to apply what I learned so far to my problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but maybe `aggregate(.~ Subject + Activity, df, mean)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think that's what they are looking for.

Comment: Also could probably take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212699/summation-of-multiple-columns-grouped-by-multiple-columns-in-r-and-output-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by David in the comments, you could do:

```
aggregate(. ~ Subject + Activity, df, mean)
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(Subject, Activity)]
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Subject, Activity) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Subject Activity meassureA    meassureB  meassureC  meassureD
#1       1  running 0.2689312 -0.051123123 -0.1150418 -0.2787436
#2       1  walking 0.2548672  0.003814723 -0.1236581 -0.2751579
#3       2  running 0.3433705 -0.014446221 -0.1673770 -0.2299235
```

Comment: Or `data.table::setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(Subject, Activity)]` if you know what you doing :)