# How to sum within columns using a for cycle in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset

I have this dataset:

```
        V1  V2  V3  V4  SN
[1]     a   t1  Q1  1   001
[2]     a   t1  Q2  2   001
[3]     a   t1  Q1  3   002
[4]     a   t1  Q2  4   002
[5]     a   t2  Q1  5   003
[6]     a   t2  Q2  6   003
[7]     b   t1  Q1  7   004
[8]     b   t3  Q1  8   005
[9]     b   t3  Q2  9   005
...     ..  ..  ..    ..
```

V1 is the customer, V2 is the product type, V3 is the quarter and V4 is the value of an economic variable.SN is the serial number, unique for each product because they are different one from each other.

I would like to create a new table that contains:

```
      V1    V2       V5   V6  V7
[1]   a     t1  1+2+3+4   2    2
[2]   a     t2      5+6   1    2     
[3]   b     t1        7   1    1
[4]   b     t3      8+9   1    2
...    ..    ...    ...   ..   ..
```

where V5 is the sum of the values contained in V4 (i would like to have 10, not 1+2+3+4); V6 is the number of the same product owned by the same customer; V7 is how many quarter are reported.

So basically I would like to have the total sum of the values contained in V4 grouped by customer and by product type.

I thought about a for or a tapply cycle but I do not know how to write it with R.

In alternative I would like to identify the rows that have same V1 and same V2 and then sum all the other variables together.

Comment: What is V6 and V7?.  If the dataset is a `data.frame`, then `aggregate(V4~V1+V2, df1, sum)` gets the V5 output

Comment: or data.table solution, dplyr, etc This has been asked many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [summation of multiple columns grouped by multiple columns in R and output results as data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212699/summation-of-multiple-columns-grouped-by-multiple-columns-in-r-and-output-result)

Comment: @Tensibai its not a dupe of the link you provided. I doubt you will find a dupe for this one.

Comment: a.rigato, There is something unclear here. If you want to group by `V2` how do you also want to count the number of same products in `V6`. Each row should have `1` in that case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it's a two pass thing, first sum V4 grouping by V1 and v2, then count unique V2 and count unique V3 grouping by V1

Comment: It's sum of `V4` and unique of `V2` and of `V3` but its still not a dupe. Also, the grouping here isn't very clear.

Comment: Something is off about your expected output. Why is row 2, column V6 `1` when customer A bought two products?

Comment: @PierreLafortune a bought one product, but it is reported for two quarters (Q1 and Q2), which is reported in column V3

Comment: @DavidArenburg I sum the V4 but I want to know how many products every customer owns. So V6 is simply the count of different products. I updated the table with the "serial number" and hopefully it will be more clear. the group is made by V1 & V2, so by customer and product type; so if a customer owns two t1 I want to report it into the next table.

Comment: So five hours after asking the question you realized that you should post the unique products? You hoped that we would use our powers of prophecy to see the individual products per type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (If you are using the development version you could use `uniqueN()` instead of `length(unique())`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(V5 = sum(V4), 
                V6 = length(unique(SN)),
                V7 = length(unique(V3))),
             by = .(V1, V2)]

#    V1 V2 V5 V6 V7
# 1:  a t1 10  2  2
# 2:  a t2 11  1  2
# 3:  b t1  7  1  1
# 4:  b t3 17  1  2
```