# R - combine rows of data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
|id|Test1|Test2|Test3| 

|01|  1  |  0  |  0  |

|01|  0  |  1  |  0  | 

|01|  0  |  0  |  1  |

|02|  0  |  0  |  0  |

|02|  0  |  1  |  0  |

|02|  0  |  0  |  1  |
```

and have the output dataframe look like:

```
 |01|  1  |  1  |  1  |

 |02|  0  |  1  |  1  |
```

Is group by on average for each test the best way to approach this?

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ id, df, sum)`?  Easy peazy lemon squeezy

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Group by multiple columns and sum other multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8212699/903061)

Comment: Is this row sums by ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by multiple columns and sum other multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212699/group-by-multiple-columns-and-sum-other-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `summarize_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize_all(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can group by on id to get the desired result. You can use the `dplyr` package for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df_agg <- df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
summarise(Test1 = sum(Test1), Test2 = sum(Test2), Test3 = sum(Test3)
```